# Declare dictionary with one key multiple values

Tags: c#, dictionary, var, class-members

C#
I am using a dictionary like:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<byte, Tuple<string, string>>();           
Tuple<string, string> t = new Tuple<string, string>(label, unit);
```

I want to declare it as a data member of the class. but it says

> The contextual keyword 'var' may only appear within a local variable declaration or in script code

How do I solve this?

Comment: Try `Dictionary<byte, Tuple<string, string>> dict = new Dictionary<byte, Tuple<string, string>>();`. In class field declaration you cannot use `var`.

Comment: Just as it says use var only as a local variable declaration or in script code. Other than that, use the type itself.

Comment: You declare it in class or inside a function as local variable? If in class, the variable should be not using var, you should
Dictionary<byte, Tuple<string, string>> dict = new Dictionary<byte, Tuple<string, string>>();

Answer (score 3):

The error message is pretty clear. You cannot use `var` to declare class members, only for local variables.

For class members you need to use the explicit type:

```
public class MyClass
{
    Dictionary<byte, Tuple<string, string>> dict = new Dictionary<byte, Tuple<string, string>>();

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

in C# you cannot use var to declare class members:

> here are technical issues with implementing this feature. The common
>   cases seem simple but the tougher cases (e.g., fields referencing
>   other fields in chains or cycles, expressions which contain anonymous
>   types) are not.

taken from the blog post [Why no var on fields?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/01/26/why-no-var-on-fields/) and from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159359/why-cant-we-declare-var-a-new-liststring-at-class-level).

In such case, you need to declare explicit types:

```
Dictionary<byte, Tuple<string, string>> dict = new Dictionary<byte, Tuple<string, string>>();
```